# Magento 2 : cannot save customer phone number

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, customer, backend

Using `Magento 2.2`, `Backend`, `Customers`. I cannot **update** or **save** suctomer telephone number, but after **Save** no message *Error*.

> Customer -> All Customer -> Customers
>   [image]

**NOTE:** This is original code, not yet **custom**.

**EDIT:**
I see *phone number* in customer information edit form, **But still not show** in table.

> Customer -> All Customer -> Customers
>   Customer Table -> Edit -> Address
>   [image]

Comment: Please try reindexing once.

Comment: Is there any index which need reindexing ?

Comment: Re-index cannot solve: `sudo php bin/magento index:reindex`

Comment: Any log entry ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customer phone number from the billing address. Once we add billding address for the customer then only the grid phone field can be validated.

Customer grid
[image]

Customer default billing address

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow this step :

- Create customer from **create an Account** from front-side.
- After create, It will redirect to My Account Page. Then, Click on
  **Address Book** tab.
- At here, You can see that **Phone number** field. Enter details which is
  required.
- Save records and refresh customer grid in admin.

It's different field from registration new customer. This field available in address book. So, We need to go to **Address Book** and add phone number after login.